# Tables sharing id column in springboot with mysql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I hava a spring-boot application that makes CRUD operations on a mysql datebase.

In thid db, there are two tables 'Employee' and 'Employee_departament' (both with auto-increment primary key and employee_id is foreign key in Employee_departament).

When I add a new employee in Employee table it will generate a record with id = 1. After that, if I add a new record in Employee_departament, this one will have id = 2.
This looks like my tables are sharing id column.

Comment: You should make a relational database.  Only have Employee with AUTO INCREMENT.  then supply the id to Employee_department as a key.  A JOIN query will be very easy to do after this.  Going down the path of two AUTO INC will end up being problematic.

Comment: Could you please show your hibernate mapping for `Employee` and `Employee_departament`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` above the id fields in both of your entities then they will both use the default database sequence (named `hibernate_sequence`) to generate new ids. This results in the behavior that you are describing.

If you want the entities to have their ids generated from separate sequences, you can specify the name of the sequence to get the ids by specifying the `generator` value inside of the `GeneratedValue` annotation. For example:

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_seq")
    private Long employee_id;
    ...
```

EmployeeDepartment.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_department")
public class EmployeeDepartment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_department_seq")
    private Long employee_department_id;
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add these two annotations into your entity class id attribute

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
```